# How can I locate a index of a selected row in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I Have this code that returns this:

IN:

```
print (df.loc[pay_date])
```

OUT:

```
High            7.515069
Low             7.515069
Open            7.515069
Close           7.515069
Volume       1392.000000
Adj Close       7.478741
Name: 2015-02-11 00:00:00, dtype: float64
```

I want to know this row index in order to select the row before this one in the df.
Any idea how to do that??

DF SAMPLE:

```
                  High  Low         Open         Close      Volume      Adj Close
Date                        
2015-01-02  29.450001   28.780001   29.215000   29.215000   614145.0    21.383413
2015-01-05  29.500000   28.455000   29.004999   28.555000   1017319.0   20.900339
2015-01-06  28.660000   27.780001   28.635000   28.000000   1083280.0   20.494114
2015-01-07  28.600000   27.955000   28.180000   28.160000   978297.0    20.611223
2015-01-08  28.875000   28.325001   28.590000   28.764999   904632.0    21.054043
```

Comment: Provide part of the dataframe in your question,

Comment: done!, posted sample of the original df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`get_loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html) method of the index:

```
df.index.get_loc(paydate)
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the `pandas.Index.get_loc` method ([pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_loc.html#pandas.Index.get_loc)).  For your case, use:

```
df.index.get_loc(pay_date)
```

For an example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3,4], 'b': [5,6,7,8]}, index=list('WXYZ'))

df
# returns:
   a  b
W  1  5
X  2  6
Y  3  7
Z  4  8

# get the index of row 'Y'
df.Index.get_loc('Y')
# returns:
2
```